# How to convert Cartesian coordinate to polar coordinate in $-180°$ to $+180°$

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, angle, cylindrical-coordinates

[image]

I wanted to plot temperature at circumference of a circle. I extracted the data by converting cartesian coordinates into polar coordinates by using ATAN2 function, but the plot is having negative and positive angles and skewed on one side (shown in Figure 1). How can I plot it symmetric with having angle in the range of $-180°$ to $+180°$ (the expected graph is shown in Figure 2). The center of the circle is at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Btw what is ATAN$2$ function? To convert cartesian coordinated to polar coordinates [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates)

Comment: atan2 is the standard function to solve this problem, but as with all things in programming, you can easily make mistakes. Maybe you should ask on StackOverflow instead, including code that people can compile and run to test what you did.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, I have got the answer. I was using ATAN2(Y,X) but it should have been ATAN2(X,Y).